# Magento2: Issue with style CSS

Tags: magento2, styles

We have an issue with load style CSS:

```
Warning: include(/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code:/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code:/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/local/php71/lib/php') in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on line 444

Warning: include(/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 160

Warning: include(/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 160

Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Config/Reader/Proxy.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code:/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/code:/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library:.:/usr/local/php71/lib/php') in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator/Io.php on line 160

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Magento\Framework\Event\Config\Reader\Proxy' not found in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #1 /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...') #4 /home/log/domains/ge in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111
```

I try to rename folder generated, deploy the system, delete pub/static/ but still, issue. Any solution?

Comment: Delete genrated/metadata and generated/code and set permission to generated folder then try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try running followings in given order.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf var/{cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed}
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Go the magento root folder and run this command.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 generated/
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

Comment: after run setup:upgrade   
Warning: include(/home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/generated/metadata/global.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/log/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager/ConfigLoader/Compiled.php on line 31

Comment: Deleting var/generation, var/cache and var/di solved it

Comment: After deleted {cache,di,generation,page_cache,view_preprocessed} sill the same issue

Comment: give permission  chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static generated/ then it'll work I hope

Comment: @Sylvester please permission to generated and var folder

Comment: unfortunately, granting permission did not solve this problem

Comment: please take backup and rm -rf vendor and then run composer install and composer update